# PHP Laravel save() is not updating record

Tags: php, laravel

I am a beginner in laravel. I was updating records but I can't figure out what is wrong with my `$student->save();`
My controller code is as follows

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Student;
use PHPUnit\Framework\MockObject\Builder\Stub;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    public function read() {
        $students = Student::all();
        return view('read',['Students'=>$students]);
    }

    public function insert() {
        return view('insert');
    }

    public function insertPost(Request $req) {
        $student=new Student();
        $student->Name = $req->input('name');
        $student->Marks = $req->input('marks');
        $student->save();
        return redirect('/');
    }

    public function update($id) {
        $student = Student::find($id);
        return view('update',['Student'=>$student]);
    }

    public function delete($id) {
        $student = Student::find($id);
        $student->delete();
    }

    public function updatePost(Request $req) {
        $student = Student::find($req->input('id'));
        $student->Name=$req->input('name');
        $student->Marks=$req->input('marks');
        $student->save();


         
        // Student::where('ID',$req->input('id'))
        //         ->update(['Name'=>$req->input('name'),
        //                   'Marks'=>$req->input('marks')]);
        return redirect('/');
    }
}
```

The Main main in `updatePost();` is causing the records not updating

```
$student = Student::find($req->input('id'));
            $student->Name=$req->input('name');
            $student->Marks=$req->input('marks');
            $student->save();
```

I changed the way of updating records to

```
Student::where('ID',$req->input('id'))
                ->update(['Name'=>$req->input('name'),
                          'Marks'=>$req->input('marks')]);
```

and it worked. But I wanted to know at which part I was making mistake in it.

Comment: Is there any error or the record just doesn't change?

Comment: no error and the record doesn't changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set your primary key to 'ID'
By default the primary key or PK name is 'id'
But in your code it changed to 'ID'
So you need to go to your User.php model class
and add this line

```php
    public $primaryKey = 'ID';
```

Comment: This worked. Is this case sensitive issue? As you mentioned by default primary key is 'id'.

Comment: Yes, your field names are CamelCaseit means start with capital letters, so Id and id and ID is different name

Comment: Ok. Next time I'll take of it.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can try is using Laravel's `update` method. `update` will handle the save internally.

```php
$student = Student::findOrFail($req->input('id')));

$student->update([
    'Name' => $req->input('name'),
    'Marks' => $req->input('marks'),
]);
```